# break a line of function in algorithm2e

Tags: algorithm2e

I tried various ways to break a line of function but did not succeed.

[image]

As you can see from the image, I was trying to break the line at the position of a function parameter. Can anybody please take a look?

```
\begin{algorithm}[t]
\DontPrintSemicolon % Some LaTeX compilers require you to use \dontprintsemicolon instead

\SetKwFunction{proc}{XXXXXXXXX}  
\SetKwProg{myproc}{XXXX}{}{}
\SetKwData{Kn}{XXXXXX}
\SetKwData{Dep}{XXX}
\SetKwData{Mt}{XXXXXXX}
\SetKwData{OMt}{XXXX}
\SetKwData{Con}{XXXXXXXX}
\SetKwData{OCon}{XXXXXXXXXXXXX}

\myproc{\proc{int \Dep,  Knowledge \Kn}}{ 
    \Begin{
         \If{\Dep $< 3$} {
                \Mt $\gets \mathit{XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX}(\Kn)$\;

            \ForEach{\OMt in \Mt}{
                    \Con $\gets \mathit{XXXXXXXXX}(\OMt)$

                \ForEach{\OCon in \Con}{
                        \Kn.$\mathit{XXXXXXXXXXX}(\OCon)$\;
                    \If{\Kn.$\mathit{XXXXX}()$} {
                            \Return{\Kn.$\mathit{XXXXXX}()$}
                         }
                    \Else{
                             \Return{XXXXXXXXX{$\Dep+1$, \Kn}}
                     }                              
                }
                 }
              }     
     }
}
```

Thanks a lot!!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think in this case the best method is to issue a new line just before the parameter, that is substitute the line

```
                    \Kn.$\mathit{XXXXXXXXXXX}(\OCon)$\;
```

with

```
                    \Kn.$\mathit{XXXXXXXXXXX}$\newline$(\OCon)$\;
```

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[vlined]{algorithm2e}

\begin{document}

\begin{algorithm}[t]
\DontPrintSemicolon % Some LaTeX compilers require you to use \dontprintsemicolon instead

\SetKwFunction{proc}{XXXXXXXXX}
\SetKwProg{myproc}{XXXX}{}{}
\SetKwData{Kn}{XXXXXX}
\SetKwData{Dep}{XXX}
\SetKwData{Mt}{XXXXXXX}
\SetKwData{OMt}{XXXX}
\SetKwData{Con}{XXXXXXXX}
\SetKwData{OCon}{XXXXXXXXXXXXX}

\myproc{\proc{int \Dep,  Knowledge \Kn}}{
    \Begin{
         \If{\Dep $< 3$} {
                \Mt $\gets \mathit{XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX}(\Kn)$\;

            \ForEach{\OMt in \Mt}{
                    \Con $\gets \mathit{XXXXXXXXX}(\OMt)$

                \ForEach{\OCon in \Con}{
                        \Kn.$\mathit{XXXXXXXXXXX}$\newline$(\OCon)$\;
                    \If{\Kn.$\mathit{XXXXX}()$} {
                            \Return{\Kn.$\mathit{XXXXXX}()$}
                         }
                    \Else{
                             \Return{XXXXXXXXX{$\Dep+1$, \Kn}}
                     }
                }
                 }
              }
     }
}
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

If you want, you can some horizontal space to emphasise the fact that the line is continuing from the above one:

```
                    \Kn.$\mathit{XXXXXXXXXXX}$\newline\hspace*{1.5em}$(\OCon)$\;
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: @user1935724 you're welcome.